# Xiaomi: what code to request permission to show app badge icon

Tags: android, xiaomi

My app gets notification, but, to show notification badgen it needs the "show app badge icon" in parameter > app > notification > show app badge icon.

[image]
What's the code for my app to ask this permission ? (prompting something that would send the user to this screen, and he can allow notification badges)

Comment: have you found any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

`notificationChannel.setShowBadge(true)`

- Notification badges are shown by default, for changing this setting programmatically we must uninstall the program first and reinstall it.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not that option. In system settings "Allow notification badges" option is not belong to any channel, it's per app. Also I've checked `notificationChannel.canShowBadge` and it is `true` while option in settings is turned off [by default].

Comment: any solution to set the notification badge on xiaomi phones?